# TFS2012 System.Description field is missing <html> and <body> tags

Tags: tfs, integration, alm

My organization recently migrated from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 and as many others we bumped into the System.Description field that was once a text field and now became an html field.

This is actually a very good thing, and long due. However, it seems that the html this field stores is not standard html. I have some scripts that query it outside the Visual Studio and what I noticed is that the field comes back without `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

Is this a bug or a feature?
If it's a feature: can this behavior be controlled somehow?

Comment: Related: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2009/01/11/using-rich-html-descriptions-instead-of-plain-text.aspx the field you're looking for is probably: `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DescriptionHtml`

Comment: For upgraded projects that is.

Answer (score 0):

The TFS API includes an `HtmlFilter` class that will strip any HTML tags that are not white-listed in the `AllowedHtmlTags` class, which `<html>` and `<body>` are not part of.

I don't believe it is a bug or a feature, but simply by design. For your scripts I would suggest adding a check for those tags and wrapping the Description field with them if they don't yet exist.